# How can I have an account before registration?

Tags: users, 8, entities

I want to make site on Drupal 8 about some events. For every past event I shall have some information, including people, who was leading that event. But they shuld be able to register on that site, and than I want to link their real profile with profile I created to show their activity on past events.

I know how to make it on Drupal 7. I was trying to make beta on Drupal Commons, and there was function for merging accounts. However not Drupal Commons, not merge module are not available on Drupal 8. But I belie it is time to make thigs on new Drupal 8, and I like lot of new features of it.

So, how to achieve same result on Drupal 8? Profile2 module are missing for Drupal 8 too. I have an idea to make separate entity for people with information about their personal info and events thy was leading in past, and just make connection them one-to-one to user accounts? Or there is a better way?

What is the best solution?

Comment: There is no "best" solution without a hard metric (speed, lines of code, # of modules, etc.) to judge by. As for the other requirements, you face a tradeoff: a quicker, more bug prone, roll-your-own solution, a slower, assist- D8-projects-to-stable-release solution, or perhaps a mix based on the current state of things and your own requirements. Pick whichever best fits all the requirements tied to the project.

Comment: Profile2 is deprecated in d8, use profile instead.

Comment: I think you've identified the problem correctly: you need to track people separately from users, and find a way to link the 2 together. CRM core looks like the most sophisticated project of this kind, but it's pre-alpha and I'm not sure where linking to user accounts is on its roadmap. I suggest rewriting your question to focus on this narrower question, how to bind user entities and people entities in a way that gives good UX.